# Enable peek/pop on links in XHTML pages

Tags: html, hyperlink, xhtml, 3dtouch

On iPhone 6S and 6S Plus, 3D touching on a link will open a preview of the page, and pressing harder will open the page. This works for pages parsed as HTML.

But a simple page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
        <title>3D Touch Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Link to <a href="//apple.com">apple</a>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If served with the `Content-Type` as `application/xhtml+xml`, peek and pop on the test link won't work. It works perfectly with the same content served as `text/html`.

How can I work around this to still have peek and pop work in an XHTML page? Am I doing something wrong here?